# How to calculate sum of unique column (column name is total) using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Controller**

This is Controller Page.

```
public function index() {
$data = array(
     'year' => $this->year_model->list_all(),
     'speces' => $this->speces_model->list_all(),
       );
          foreach ($data['year'] as $value):

                $temp = array();
                $temp['year_key'] = $value['year-range'];
                $temp['year_id'] = $value['id'];


                $temp['speces_key'] = array();
                foreach ($data['speces'] as $value1):

                    $temp['speces_key'][$value1['name']] = $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('spacesId' => $value1['id'], 'yearId' => $value['id']))->row_array();

                endforeach;
                $final_result[] = $temp;

            endforeach;
            $data['result'] = $final_result;
            $this->load->view('site/template', $data);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function list_all() {
        return $this->db->get('year')->result_array();
    }
```

**View**

This is View file.

```
<table>
 <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Year Range</th>
          <?php foreach ($speces as $value): ?>
            <th> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></th>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
         <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
                  <?php $sum = 0; ?>
                    <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $value['year_key']; ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($value['speces_key'] as $key => $value2): ?>
                  <td><?php echo $value2['data']; ?></td>
                     <?php $sum+= $value2['data']; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>
                   </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

            <tr>
               <td>Total</td>
                  <?php foreach ($speces as $value6): ?>
  <?php
  $this->db->select_sum('data');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('spacesId' => $value6['id']))->row_array();

 $totals = $query['data'];                                      
     ?>
      <td><?php echo $totals; ?></td>    
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI1i0.png)]

My Question: How to calculate sum of column (column name is total).column name total is display above screenshot.so how to calculate sum of column(column name is total) and sum display in red arrow in above screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to calculate sum of total column which is not a database field. So to do that you can take a variable in which you will addup the column value of every row.

Just Initialize a variable to zero.

`<?php $sum = $totalSum = 0; ?>`

Now add value of sum variable for every row.
change your line,

`<td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>`

with

`<td><?php $totalSum+=$sum; echo $sum; ?></td>`

Now your `$totalSum` field will have the sum of your total column. You can show it where ever you want.

UPDATED 
Use this in your view file and check.

```
    <table>
     <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Year Range</th>
              <?php foreach ($speces as $value): ?>
                <th> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></th>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
             <tbody>
                     <?php $totalSum=0; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
                      <?php $sum = 0; ?>
                        <tr>
                         <td><?php echo $value['year_key']; ?></td>
                    <?php foreach ($value['speces_key'] as $key => $value2): ?>
                      <td><?php echo $value2['data']; ?></td>
                         <?php $sum+= $value2['data']; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <td><?php $totalSum+= $sum; echo $sum; ?></td>
                       </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>

                <tr>
                   <td>Total</td>
                      <?php foreach ($speces as $value6): ?>
      <?php
      $this->db->select_sum('data');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('spacesId' => $value6['id']))->row_array();

     $totals = $query['data'];                                      
         ?>
          <td><?php echo $totals; ?></td>    
          <?php endforeach; ?>
<td><?php echo $totalSum; ?></td>    
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: sum can not calculate

Comment: you see my screen shot,and my screenshot display red arrow ,this red arrow display sum of total column (column name  total)

Comment: @kishankakadiya updated my answer, Please check, if it works?

Comment: Sorry my bad,it must be showing the total of last row. if so i have Updated the code. it should work fine now.

Comment: i have updated the code, it will work fine. i guess.

Comment: tell me your answer?

Comment: Actually if it is showing the total of last row then, you should try to rectify it, because as per the logic. It will add value of `$sum` variable to the `$totalSum` but somehow it is overwritting it. 
the problem i identified was , `$totalSum` variable was initialized in foreach loop, so i moved it just before the foreach, but if still showing the same. Please check where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 <?php $sum = $sum + $value2['data']; ?>
```

instead of

```
 <?php $sum+= $value2['data']; ?>
```

Comment: how to calculate total